# SIGABRT when returning from function

Tags: c, return, callstack, sigabrt

my problem is that, just as I mentioned on the title, i have a function that, upon return, causes a SIGABRT to be raised. I ran valgrind on my program and I got this at that exact point.

```
==5807== Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT)
==5807==    at 0x52F5428: raise (raise.c:54)
==5807==    by 0x52F7029: abort (abort.c:89)
==5807==    by 0x53377E9: __libc_message (libc_fatal.c:175)
==5807==    by 0x53D911B: __fortify_fail (fortify_fail.c:37)
==5807==    by 0x53D90BF: __stack_chk_fail (stack_chk_fail.c:28)
==5807==    by 0x402E8B: foo (file.c:43)
==5807==    by 0x202C27323939312C: ???
==5807==    by 0x592D4D4D2D444426: ???
==5807==    by 0x66202C2927595958: ???
==5807==    by 0x2965736C60: ???
==5807==    by 0x505770F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2.0.0)

==5807==
```

This is the code i'm executing, the stack error causes the abort at the return ret statement from add_user:

```
int add_user(SQLHDBC dbc, char * mail, char * password, char * name,  char * date) {

char query[TAM];
SQLHSTMT stmt;
SQLRETURN ret;

if (mail == NULL || password == NULL || name == NULL ||  date == NULL)
    return ERR;

sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO mms_user values (default,'%s',encrypt_password('%s'),set_type(),'%s',to_date('%s', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), false)", mail, password, name,date);

ret= DBExecuteQuery(dbc, query, &stmt);

DBFreeHandle(&stmt);
return ret;
}

int DBExecuteQuery(SQLHDBC dbc, char * query, SQLHSTMT *stmt) {

SQLRETURN ret;

/*Error control*/
if (query == NULL || stmt == NULL)
    return ERR;

/*Allocates memory for a new statement*/
ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbc, stmt);
if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
    return ERR;
}

/*Executes query and stores result in stmt*/
ret = SQLExecDirect(*stmt, (SQLCHAR *)query, SQL_NTS);
if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
    return ERR;

return OK;

}

int DBFreeHandle(SQLHSTMT * stmt){

 int ret;
  /*Frees allocated memory*/
  ret = SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, *stmt);
  if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
      return ERR;
  }

}
```

The function executes normally as far as I have checked. I don't know what could be happening, if any of you could provide any possible explanation, I would be really thankful. Also feel free to ask for further information (this is the only useful info I've been taught to look for, so I might need some guidance in that case).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you construct a [mcve]?

Comment: You're smashing the stack in the function... *stack overflow*.

Comment: What is happening is that your function has a bug where it damages the stack, likely your code are writing past the bounds of an array. You need to show us that code if you want further help though.

Comment: Okay, I added the code.

Comment: `char query[TAM]; ... sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO mms_user values (default,'%s',encrypt_password('%s'),set_type(),'%s',to_date('%s', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), false)", mail, password, name,date);`?!?!?!  No bounds checking at all?

Comment: every time you feel like writing some code which runs SQL queries from C code stop for a second and consider whether you have made any wrong choices in your prior life.

Comment: And what should i do instead? @MK.

Comment: at least use snprintf. The run through each parameter and work out how big a string you need and malloc a big enough buffer. Of course you should real be using paramterized queries (assuming yr driver supports it)

Comment: I added control for each parameter's length, now it's done :) @pm100

Comment: Write the code that interfaces to the database in a higher level language.  Java, Python, Go.    Expose your interactions with the database as a service which can be invoked from your legacy C code if needed.  If that's not an option, at least write it in C++.

Comment: Hmm... I'll think about it. Thanks @MK.

Comment: @RobertoSánchez while we are all big boys and girls here, we try and maintain a modicum of decency in the language used on this site. No ding for it, but just try and remember an educated man can express the same sentiment without dropping into the gutter to do it `:)`

Comment: Understood @DavidC.Rankin. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

This code is dangerous:

```
char query[TAM];
 .
 .
 .
sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO mms_user values"
    " (default,'%s',encrypt_password('%s'),set_type(),"
    "'%s',to_date('%s', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), false)",
     mail, password, name,date);
```

You do absolutely no bounds checking so it will overflow your stack easily.

Comment: Inputs are checked not to be NULL. I had not yet added the param checking functions (where I also check the bounds). Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: @RobertoSánchez Fixed.  Sorry. I confused that with some other code I was reviewing.  Human minds are not meant to multitask, no matter what anyone tells you...